# Rails, how do load another page directly to a dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a page call /informations which i want to load into my main /home page inside one of my div.

i tried doing render :template, but i need to declare all the variables again in my home controller, is there anyway that i can do it, so that it does not only loads the view, it also loads the informations controller then the view.

one method that i am using is link_to remote, then jquery div.html. but this is on click event and seems hackish to me, is there a proper way?

Comment: do you want page render using ajax? if not you can use partial.

Comment: partial is not working, is only loads the view, without the controller, therefore no global variables at all

Comment: you can pass variable in partial like :locals=>{:abc=>@abc} etc

Answer (score 0):

You could just put it inside of an iframe, like this `<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>`. Iframes are used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rendering the /informations page via a partial and passing in the required variables through locals:

```
render partial: 'informations', locals: {first_variable: @first_variable, second_variable: @second_variable}
```